# Use expression for input value in template

Tags: angular

```
<input 
    ngModel 
    name='quantity'
    placeholder='Quantity'
    type="number"
    class="form-control"
    pattern="^\d*(\.\d{0,2})?$" 
    required />

<input
    ngModel
    name='price'
    class="form-control"
    placeholder='Price'
    type="number"
    required />

<input 
    name='total' 
    class="form-control" 
    type="number" 
    [value]='addRowForm.value.quantity * addRowForm.value.price' />
```

I have three input fields **Quantity, Price, Total**, The multiplication of quantity and price should be shown in the Total field, I can do this in Typescript code, But I wonder there is a simple solution to do it solely in the template.

I have tried this but it doesn't work.

`[value]='addRowForm.value.quantity * addRowForm.value.price'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `[(ngModel)]` in the fields.

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qqjhbx?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="quantity" name='quantity' placeholder='Quantity' type="number" class="form-control" pattern="^\d*(\.\d{0,2})?$" required />

<input [(ngModel)]="price" name='price' class="form-control" placeholder='Price' type="number" required />

<input name='total' class="form-control" type="number" [(ngModel)]='quantity * price' />
```

You can also use it like this:

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lsgbfy?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

TS:

```
newRowDetails = {}
```

Template:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="newRowDetails.quantity" name='quantity' placeholder='Quantity' type="number" class="form-control" pattern="^\d*(\.\d{0,2})?$" required />

<input [(ngModel)]="newRowDetails.price" name='price' class="form-control" placeholder='Price' type="number" required />

<input name='total' class="form-control" type="number" [(ngModel)]='newRowDetails.quantity * newRowDetails.price' />
```

Comment: Although it is working, but vscode is complaining that the Identifiers quantity and price are not defined.

Comment: Thats why define it like this: `newRowDetails = {}`. Whatever you add in `ngModel` that should be defined. For the first wat, you can add `price`, `qualtity` etc in TS

Comment: I had to define those properties in the typescript file in order to get rid of the error, thanks

Comment: Yes.. That is the proper way to bond models in Angular

Answer (score 0):

Try this,  use *double quotes* to evaluate the value of your variable.

```
<input  name="total" class="form-control" type="number" [value]="addRowForm.value.quantity * addRowForm.value.price" />
```